# correct code for concatenating substrings that are part of a particular field of a table to create new field

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am using MySQL 5.6.26 with Sequel Pro on Mac OS X.  I would like to create a new field called `Game_date` in the table `starting_pitcher_game_log`.  In order to create this field, I have to extract and attach substrings from another field in this table called `GAME_ID`.  This is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE starting_pitcher_game_log ADD Game_date INTEGER;
UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log 
SET Game_date = CONCAT(SUBSTR(GAME_ID,4,4),'-',SUBSTR(GAME_ID,10,2),'-',SUBSTR(GAME_ID,12,2)) 
FROM game
WHERE game.GAME_ID = starting_pitcher_game_log.GAME_ID
```

I get the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM game WHERE game.GAME_ID =
>   starting_pitcher_game_log.GAME_ID' at line 3

Can someone offer guidance on what's wrong with the code here?

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Thank you in advance.

update of status following Subin's code changes:
Thanks for your help Subin. Not working. I deleted field with null values. Then I put in your original code:

`ALTER TABLE starting_pitcher_game_log ADD Game_date INTEGER; 
UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log 
INNER JOIN game ON game.GAME_ID = starting_pitcher_game_log.GAME_ID 
SET starting_pitcher_game_log.Game_date = CONCAT(SUBSTR(game.GAME_ID,4,4),'-',SUBSTR(game.GAME_ID,10,2),'-',SUBSTR(gam‌​e.GAME_ID,12,2))`

It gives an error: Unknown column 'starting_pitcher_game_log.Game_date' in 'field list'. When I add "COLUMN" after "ADD", the query runs but only adds null values to the column.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[view of sequel pro of MySQL database table in question "starting_pitcher_game_log"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqfPS.png)

Subin, With your changes, the query runs eery time, but it still leaves the Game_id column with "null" on each row of that column.  above is a screenshot of the table contents view of the starting_pitcher_game_log table.  the "Game_ID" column is there, and this is where I have been trying to extract the information from to create the Game_date column--the date is expressed between character numbers 4 through 11.  I'm not sure if this will help.

In any case, thank you for your help.

Update:

Here is the code that worked:

```
ALTER TABLE retrosheet.starting_pitcher_game_log ADD COLUMN Game_Date DATE;
UPDATE retrosheet.starting_pitcher_game_log AS b,
retrosheet.game AS g
SET b. Game_Date = CONCAT(SUBSTR(g.`GAME_ID`,4,4),'-',SUBSTR(g.`GAME_ID`,8,2),'-',SUBSTR(g.`GAME_ID`,10,2))
WHERE b.`Game_ID` = g.`GAME_ID`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JOIN with your `UPDATE()`.

```
ALTER TABLE starting_pitcher_game_log ADD Game_date VARCHAR(15);
UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log 
  INNER JOIN  game ON game.`GAME_ID` = starting_pitcher_game_log.`GAME_ID`
SET starting_pitcher_game_log.`Game_date` = CONCAT(SUBSTR(game.`GAME_ID`,4,4),'-',SUBSTR(game.`GAME_ID`,10,2),'-',SUBSTR(game.`GAME_ID`,12,2))
```

Alternative way of achieving same result without using `JOIN` keyword .

```
UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log ,game
SET starting_pitcher_game_log.`Game_date` = CONCAT(SUBSTR(game.`GAME_ID`,4,4),'-',SUBSTR(game.`GAME_ID`,10,2),'-',SUBSTR(game.`GAME_ID`,12,2)) 
WHERE  game.`GAME_ID` = starting_pitcher_game_log.`GAME_ID`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A column is created from first line of code, but only with Null values in each row of the column produced.  The rest of the code gives error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log.Game_date
INNER JOIN  game ON game.`GAME_ID` = ' at line 2

Comment: `UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log.Game_date INNER JOIN` ==> `UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log 
  INNER JOIN  game ON game.`GAME_ID`

Comment: You have to give `table_name` after `UPDATE` not the column name as you have given (`UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log.Game_date INNER JOIN`). Thats why the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help Subin. Not working. I deleted field with null values.  Then I put in your original code: ALTER TABLE starting_pitcher_game_log ADD Game_date INTEGER;
UPDATE starting_pitcher_game_log 
INNER JOIN  game ON game.`GAME_ID` = starting_pitcher_game_log.`GAME_ID`
SET starting_pitcher_game_log.`Game_date` = CONCAT(SUBSTR(game.`GAME_ID`,4,4),'-',SUBSTR(game.`GAME_ID`,10,2),'-',SUBSTR(game.`GAME_ID`,12,2)) and it gives error: Unknown column 'starting_pitcher_game_log.Game_date' in 'field list'.  When I add "COLUMN" after "ADD", the query runs but only adds null values to the column

Comment: I have edited the query with `Game_date`- column as `VARCHAR(30)`,[This is not the solution] ...give it try if it works, then there is a fix for your problem

Comment: Hi Subin,  What you gave me helped a lot--it pretty much worked except that the initial substring value for the different components of 'GAME_ID' that make up the date were not correct.  Please see update in original post with the code that worked.  Also I changed the variable type from VARCHAR to DATE.

Comment: Those errors were my own as they were in the code  that I originally introduced in the original post. Thanks again for your help